# Почему элементы inline-block переносятся на новую строку?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть список, который я хочу превратить в горизонтальное меню. Почему, указывая элементам (в данном случае li) `inline-block`, они не выстраиваются в одну линию, а продолжают вести себя как блочные, выстраиваясь один под одного?

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.menu_block {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu_block li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.menu_block li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.menu_block ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 270px;
}

.btn a {
    padding: 18px 35px;
    background: #ff7340;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Pf81DpN4/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="menu_block">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">meet us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <a href="#">adventures</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы применяете значение `inline-block` к тегу `anchor`, который находиться ***внутри*** тега `li`, Вам нужно либо переписать верстку с учетом этого, либо воспользоваться вариантами типа [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu_block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 80px;
}

.menu_block ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu_block ul li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu_block li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu_block li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.menu_block ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn a {
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Pf81DpN4/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="menu_block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">meet us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">adventures</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Да, с flex все отлично работает, но я не понимаю почему все также отлично не работает с inline-block

Comment: Ах, да! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы `display: inline-block` задаёте `<a>`, а не `<li>`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu_block {
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu_block li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu_block li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu_block li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.btn a {
  padding: 18px 35px;
  background: #ff7340;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Pf81DpN4/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="menu_block">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">meet us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#">adventures</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```